# How to filter array of object to match a list?

Tags: javascript, json

Given a large data of 400.000 such :

```
var data = [
 {
  "kDefinition": "ford stream, wade across", 
  "kMandarin": "shè", 
  "char": "涉", 
  "kCantonese": "sip3", 
  "kJapaneseKun": "WATARU KAKAWARU", 
 }, 
 {
  "kDefinition": "to pierce, to stab; to take", 
  "kMandarin": "jué", 
  "char": "鈌", 
  "kCantonese": "kyut3", 
  "kJapaneseKun": "SASU"
 },
 ...
]
```

And given a smaller 1000 units subset-list matching the `char` field as :

```
var list = ['早', '维', '基', '涉', '百', ..., '科', '月']
```

How to reduce the larger data to only keep the 1000 objects for whom `obj.char` is present in `list` ?

**Edit:** `list` and `data` are not sorted in the same order.

Comment: Is the data sorted?

Comment: nope, it isn't .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn your `list` array to `Set` and then use `has()` method inside filter, as suggested by @Amadan.

```js
var data = [{"kDefinition":"ford stream, wade across","kMandarin":"shè","char":"涉","kCantonese":"sip3","kJapaneseKun":"WATARU KAKAWARU"},{"kDefinition":"to pierce, to stab; to take","kMandarin":"jué","char":"鈌","kCantonese":"kyut3","kJapaneseKun":"SASU"}]
var list = ['早', '维', '基', '涉', '百', '科', '月']  

list = new Set(list)

const result = data.filter(({char}) => list.has(char));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I'd suggest turning `list` into a `Set` first, for faster membership lookup. 400000 times sequential `includes` check can't be fun.

Comment: Indeed just so.

Comment: Here is a test https://jsperf.com/array-vs-map-js-test1, not sure if that is correct.

Comment: It is correct; "Map" (37.83 ops/s) is 122x faster on my Chrome than "array" (0.31 ops/s). Of course, the data is not quite representative, as it either misses (6 out of 7 times) or gets a hit within the first 4 elements of `list` in the "array" case. In the real situation, it would either miss (399000 times out of 400000) or get a hit on avg at 500th element (1000 times out of 400000), and would thus be even slower.

Comment: sets and maps, on a fundamental level, are leaps and bounds faster for lookup. Searching an array is O(n). Searching in a set or map is O(1).

Answer (score 1):

For lists of this size I would consider using old school loops. It will generally be the fastest, and it is almost as easy as any more modern solution.

```js
var data = [
 {
  "kDefinition": "ford stream, wade across", 
  "kMandarin": "shè", 
  "char": "涉", 
  "kCantonese": "sip3", 
  "kJapaneseKun": "WATARU KAKAWARU", 
 }, 
 {
  "kDefinition": "to pierce, to stab; to take", 
  "kMandarin": "jué", 
  "char": "鈌", 
  "kCantonese": "kyut3", 
  "kJapaneseKun": "SASU"
 }
];

var list = [ '早', '维', '基', '涉', '百', '科', '月' ];

// First, make an object from the char list
var chars = {};
for( var i = 0, n = list.length;  i < n;  ++i ) {
    chars[ list[i] ] = true;
}

// Now we can match against the data
var output = [];
for( var i = 0, n = data.length;  i < n;  ++i ) {
    if( chars.hasOwnProperty( data[i].char ) ) {
        output.push( data[i] );
    }
}

console.log( JSON.stringify( output, null, 4 ) );
```